# is apple allow to process payments in my own system in this case?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store

I have a non-technical question, I built an app that let people to book halls in my building and I want to let people pay in the app. **my question is can I use any payments system or apple don’t allow me to do this**.

I search over the internet but i con't find answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you should use in-app purchase if the purchased item or subscription consumed on the app such as coins, video and music stream etc. Otherwise you can use your payment system. On your case I believe you can use your own system.

For more information you can read Apple's review Guidelines.

Section 3.1.1

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Your welcome! You can mark the answer if it is solved your problem.